# Print list of elements in Python

Tags: python, arrays, xpath

I got list of elements like:

```
//*[@id="easPanelGrid_item_0"]/td[3], //*[@id="easPanelGrid_item_1"]/td[3], //*[@id="easPanelGrid_item_2"]/td[3], etc.
```

I need to print them all. Here is my code so far:

```
try:
    for i in range(1, 23):
        name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easPanelGrid_item_[%d]"]/td[3]' % (i)).text
        print(name)
```

Guys, thank you, all good now. Solution:

```
        try:
            for i in range(1, 23):
                name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="easPanelGrid_item_%d"]/td[3]' % (i))
                print(name.text)
```

Comment: ... you tell me... what is wrong?

Comment: program prints nothing. no error messages. So please correct if you can

Comment: `try` ... => let me guess: `except: pass` ?

Comment: I don't understand the answer. I added the rest of my code, can you please think what could be wrong and let me know. THx

Comment: my cristal ball was right :) `except: pass`. Of course you don't get any error messages...

Comment: try removing `except NoSuchElementException:
        pass` and see what happens. Plus this throws you out of your loop if one element is missing, skipping the following elements...

Comment: but how come there is no such element, if there is?

Comment: probably because you made a mistake when generating their names. like quotes or whatever (I don't know the technology)